# proto file, generated code in python and go

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers, proto, grpc-python

I am trying to generate python and go code using same proto file.

My proto file looks like:

```
message City {
  string name = 1;
  int32 street_no = 2;
}
```

When I generate the code in python using below command:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc  -I proto/ --python_out=openconfig/ --grpc_python_out=openconfig/ proto/city.proto
```

then the variables names remain in snake_case, but when the proto file is generatd in go code using below:

```
${PROTOC} --gogofaster_out=proto --proto_path proto proto/city.proto
```

then the generated variables are in CamelCase.
so, street_no changes to StreetNo

Is there any way to convert the python code also in CamelCase instead of snake_case?
How to work in different languages with the same proto file?

I tried with `protoc` as well as below:

```
${PROTOC} --python_out=proto --proto_path proto/city.proto
```

still, it generates the python code in snake_case.

Thanks,

- M -

Answer (score 0):

Protobufs are generated in the standard formatting of the given language (aka CamelCase for Go and snake_case for Python. If it generated a different way, you would have linter flags for having CamelCase in Python. Is there any reason that the variables need to have the same name in the different languages?